# find if an array is inside another nested array

Tags: javascript

I 'm trying to find if `array1` is is inside the nested `array2.data`.

```
    const array1 = [
  {
    name: "Color",
    value: "Yellow",
  },
  {
    name: "Size",
    value: "Small",
  },
];



const array2 =     [
  {
      "id": 1,
      "data": [
          {
              "name": "Color",
              "value": "Yellow"
          },
          {
              "name": "Size",
              "value": "Small"
          }
      ]
  },
  {
      "id": 2,
      "data": [
          {
              "name": "Color",
              "value": "Yellow"
          },
          {
              "name": "Size",
              "value": "Medium"
          }
      ]
  },
  {
      "id": 3,
      "data": [
          {
              "name": "Color",
              "value": "Yellow"
          },
          {
              "name": "Size",
              "value": "Large"
          }
      ]
  },]
```

this is what I have tread but not giving me the result I need :

```
array2.map((  a ) => {
  a.data.map(( data ) => {
    array1.map((option) => {
      if( data === option) {
         return data;
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`JSON.stringify()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) the needle array (`array1`) and the `data` attribute of each array member in `array2` and compare the two; if they match, `array1` *is* present in `array2`:

```js
const array1 = [{
    name: "Color",
    value: "Yellow",
  },
  {
    name: "Size",
    value: "Small",
  },
];

const array2 = [{
    "id": 1,
    "data": [{
        "name": "Color",
        "value": "Yellow"
      },
      {
        "name": "Size",
        "value": "Small"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "data": [{
        "name": "Color",
        "value": "Yellow"
      },
      {
        "name": "Size",
        "value": "Medium"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "data": [{
        "name": "Color",
        "value": "Yellow"
      },
      {
        "name": "Size",
        "value": "Large"
      }
    ]
  },
];

const dataArrayIsPresentInArray2 = needle => !!array2.find(cv => JSON.stringify(cv.data) === JSON.stringify(needle));

console.log(dataArrayIsPresentInArray2(array1)); // true
```

As mentioned in the comments, this method will only work for data structures serializable with `JSON.stringify()`.

Comment: That will work in this case, but it should be noted that there's a large class of objects that `JSON.stringify()` will reject, or for which the result will be missing properties of the original object (due to type issues, like Date instances for example).

Comment: not working, it return false even though array1 is inside the array2.data

Comment: @hicham The snippet returns `true` for me as-is; it's not clear how you would be getting `false` here.

Answer (score 0):

If the order of the objects in `array1` does not matter, you can iterate through every item and use [`Array.every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) to check whether each item in the `data` property after stringification is equal to an item in `array1` after stringification.

```js
const array1=[{name:"Color",value:"Yellow"},{name:"Size",value:"Small"}],array2=[{id:1,data:[{name:"Color",value:"Yellow"},{name:"Size",value:"Small"}]},{id:2,data:[{name:"Color",value:"Yellow"},{name:"Size",value:"Medium"}]},{id:3,data:[{name:"Color",value:"Yellow"},{name:"Size",value:"Large"}]}];

const contains = array2.some(e => e.data.every(f => array1.some(g => JSON.stringify(g) == JSON.stringify(f))));
console.log(contains)
```

Answer (score 0):

if you wanna just to check if arr1 in arr2.date

i would probably just
loop over arr2.data and compare each iteration to arr1 and if it is the same return or change some value to know the output .

something like :

```js
// var that represent if arr1 inside arr2.data
let arr1InsideArr2= false

for (let i of array2){
if (i.data == array1){
 return arr1InsideArr2= true 
}
}
```

and then do with the var `arr1InsideArr2` whatever you want to check .